# the meaning of these reading (Neither and Nor)

Tags: meaning, north-american-english, neither-nor

1. What is the meaning of the sentence in bold?

> How might this inability to recall early experiences be explained? The
> sheer passage of time does not account for it; adults have excellent
> recognition of pictures of people who attended high school with them 35
> years earlier. Another seemingly plausible explanation—that infants do not
> form enduring memories at this point in development—also is incorrect.
> Children two and a half to three years old remember experiences that
> occurred in their first year, and eleven month olds remember some events
> a year later. **Nor does the hypothesis that infantile amnesia reflects
> repression—or holding back—of sexually charged episodes explain the
> phenomenon.** While such repression may occur, people cannot remember
> ordinary events from the infant and toddler periods either.

2. And my second question is why ***Nor*** is used without ***Neither***.

Comment: "Nor does the hypothesis [described] explain the phenomenon." The 'nor' refers to something previously mentioned, which you have not shown.

Comment: We don't do those chores here. But the sentence is a little complicated. The sentence before probably addressed the hypothesis. This one goes further. It says that the suggestion (hypothesis) that a baby forgets sexual events *because it holds feeling inside* does not explain the situation (the phenom).

Comment: @79037662 accept my apologies. I meant following sentence.

Comment: @WeatherVane I provided whole paragraph.

Comment: Previous sentences say *this* and *that* **do not** explain the phenomonen. **Nor** does the originally posted sentence. If they had used **neither** there could have been only one reason: neither ... nor, but two possible reasons were already given.

Comment: @Cascabel Oh yes. Thanks. One reason for not using monospaced text, and highlighting the problem in-situ. I'll do that.

Comment: There was, in my distant schooldays an official teachers' embargo on starting sentences with conjunctions, ans especially 'and' and 'but'.  There was no reason for this, and the 'rule' is better described as a convention.  'Nor' is a case of this 'embargo'.  By now the embargo should have been lifted, though its dying embers continue to smoulder away.  One result of this residual resistance to starting with 'Nor' is that when it appear, I sit up and pay attention.  That is the function of starting a sentence with 'Nor' without an either.

Comment: @Tuffy u mean that it's ok to use nor without neither?

Comment: A very similar question was asked before. [Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/521112/155553) is an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane u mean that it's because that the text offers 3 reasons?

Comment: @ali In a single sentence 'nor' must be preceded by 'neither'.  Note that when 'not' is used at the beginning of a new sentence, the subject and verb must be inverted, as in your example.

Comment: @Tuffy you mentioned ***not*** did u mean ***nor***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Meaning:  Some people suggest that you can't remember things from your early childhood (infantile amnesia) because your brain is repressing sexual trauma/abuse.  That theory doesn't make sense, because you also can't remember ordinary events.
2. Can't say for certain but "Nor does xxx explain the phenomenon" sounds much more natural than "Neither does xxx explain the phenomenon"

Comment: why Nor looks more natural rather than Neither?

Comment: As a native English speaker, I don't know WHY it's more correct, but when speaking each one, to me it's clear that that 'nor' is the correct word choice.  "Neither thing 1 nor thing 2 was the correct option".  Nor is almost like a negated "and" in its usage.