# 'Nor WE are' and 'Nor ARE we'

Tags: word-order, conjunctions, neither-nor

I was listening to a speech the other day and I heard the speaker saying

> We are not in a position to see it nor are we in a position to understand it.

If the speaker is right to say "nor are we", why is that? Or should it actually be "nor we are"?

Comment: Addressed at [Confusing nor ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521103/confusing-nor/521112#521112).

Comment: (Just playing with the title to see if it might increase the views and get you some other answers)

Answer (score 5):

Negation words at the beginning of a sentence entail Subject-Verb inversion:

> In linguistics, ***negative inversion*** is one of many types of *subject–auxiliary inversion* in English. *A negation* (e.g. ***not, no, never, nothing***, etc.) *or a word that implies negation* (***only, hardly, scarcely***) *or a phrase containing one of these words*, precedes the finite auxiliary verb, **necessitating that the subject and finite verb undergo inversion**. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_inversion))

*Nor* is a negation and therefore requires this inversion:

> When a clause with *neither* or ***nor*** is used after a negative clause, *we invert the subject and the verb after neither and **nor***:
>
> - We didn’t get to see the castle, ***nor*** *did we see* the cathedral. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2))

Comment: Hmmm, only half the story. How about *Neither James nor John completed their homework*? Or *For no reason, Trump would dance naked*,  or *Never tired, she completed all her tasks with a cheerful optimism*?

Comment: Care to say the other half?

Comment: Yes, sure. Negative phrases at the beginning of a tensed clause cause SAI only when the negation scopes over the rest of the clause (in other words if they turn the clause into a negative clause). Compare: *For no money **would Trump** dance naked* and alternatively *For no money **Trump would** dance naked*. There's no dancing in the former, but there is in the latter. Second, the negative phrase must precede the subject/auxiliary. Negative words at the beginning of a clause/sentence don't cause SAI if they are within the Subject NP.